# Unexpected behaviour when writing file with invalid name on Windows

Tags: java, io, filesystems

In a project of mine I experienced a quite unexpected behaviour when writing a file to a local file system in MS Windows using Java.
The filename was generated by the application and contains an invalid char ':'. The program did not guard against that (it is now), but I expected an IOException on writing content to that file. The situation is however far more wierd.

Here is an SSCE of what I am experiencing:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class FileWriter {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File home = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    final String fileName = "invalidf:ile.txt";

    // Some cleanup if you rerun the example
    File otherFile = new File(home, "invalidf");
    if (otherFile.exists()) {
      assertTrue(otherFile.delete());
    }
    File file = new File(home, fileName);
    if (file.exists()) {
      assertTrue(file.delete());
    }

    // The real scenario. Writing some content to an illegal file name
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    final String content = "some test content";
    out.write(content.getBytes());
    out.close();

    // Since the write operation does not throw an exception, it is expected some file has been written
    assertTrue(file.isFile());
    assertTrue(file.canRead());

    // This should usually throw an exception since the file was deleted in the cleanup section.
    assertTrue(otherFile.exists());

    // Now we try to read the data and make sure it really got stored.
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    assert in.available() > 0;
    byte[] fileContent = new byte[in.available()];
    assertTrue(in.read(fileContent) == content.getBytes().length);
    assertTrue(Arrays.equals(fileContent, content.getBytes()));
  }

  private static void assertTrue(boolean flag) {
    if (!flag) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Assertion failed!");
    }
  }
}
```

So what is the issue then:
Windows lists a new file `invalidf` instead of `invalidf:ile.txt` as expected. The file size is shown as 0 bytes and reading that file (with editor and with Java code) returns no content. The originally written file does not seem to exist.

Reading the file `invalidf:ile.txt` with Java however shows the originally written content (as shown in the code above).

So what is the issue here? Seems as if there are two files available. One visible, but seemingly empty file and one "hidden" file with the real content. If I however delete the empty file, the "hidden" file can also not be accessed anymore. So the filesystem seems to treat both files as the same.

Maybe this is related to the Windows and Java version I am using (tested with Java 6 and Windows 7).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a search for "Windows Alternate Data Streams". An explanation [here](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-alternate-data-streams/).

The alternate data stream is a, well, data stream attached to a file, but independent of the main file contents. It seems the ":" is the way to specify ADS in Windows. From the link above, you can read the content of the alternate stream as:

```
notepad invalidf:ile.txt
```

Comment: Never a day without learning something new. Thanks a lot for this answer.